# Is there a way to get a stripe token from apple pay in ionic?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, applepay

I have an ionic project that I'm using stripe to get payments from the user and it works great. However, apple won't allow the application on the app store without me adding in apple pay. Using a cordova plugin, I was able to get apple pay functioning in the application and returning a token. However, I want to be able to send that payment to stripe. According to stripe's website, it works with apple pay, so I have been trying to figure out a way to either get a stripe token from apple pay or convert the apple pay token into a stripe token. So far, I haven't been able to figure out a solution to this, do any of you have an idea on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I was not aware of any requirement for apps to support ApplePay. Before you go too much further you should double check the message from Apple. Are you certain they don't want you to use in-app purchase. This is different to ApplePay. External payment systems like stripe and ApplePay can only be used for goods and services delivered outside the app. IAP must be used for digital goods and services delivered in the app.

Comment: The stripe documentation for native apps is [here](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay) you should be able to use that to help you work with Cordova. You need to get a payment secret from your server (that communicates with Stripe's servers) and use that to complete the payment process on the mobile device.

Comment: Sending Apple Pay info to Stripe seems to defeat the purpose of making an app integrate Apple Pay since then Apple won't get their cut. It seems more like you need to implement both.   https://medium.com/enappd/payment-solutions-in-ionic-8c4bb28ce5cc

Comment: @E.Maggini Again, don't confuse Apple Pay and In-App Purchase.  Apple Pay payments are always processed through an external payment processor, such as Stripe, and Apple doesn't take anything from the transaction (at least not directly from the purchaser or merchant; they may get a fee from the transaction processor who does collect merchant fees).  IAP is for digitals good and services delivered through the app, Apple does take 15% or 30% and Apple handles the payment.

Comment: @Paulw11Indeed you are correct, Sir. :) I learned something new about Apple Pay re: fees.

Comment: @matt-opsitnick what have you tried so far? Could you please post code of current approach? It will help get better answers. And since you are in an Ionic app, is using a javascript solution an option? https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button

Comment: @E.Maggini the stripe payment request button will not work from inside an Ionic app as it needs to come from a local urlScheme of "https://" and ionic/iOS will not allow this.

Comment: Did you end up getting this to work as I am struggling to find a way to implement Apple Pay in Ionic.  The app store requires Apple pay as an option for non profit donations.